# Set the values out of the defined interval limits to a given value (f.e. NaN) for a column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, limit

Having a defined interval limits of valid values, all the pandas data frame column values out of it should be set to a given value, f.e. `NaN`. The values defining limits and data frame contents can be assumed to be of numerical type.

Having the following limits and data frame:

```
min = 2
max = 7
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 1, 7, 22],'b': [12, 3 , 10, 9]})

    a   b
0   5  12
1   1   3
2   7  10
3  22   9
```

Setting the limit on column `a` would result in:

```
     a   b
0    5  12
1  NaN   3
2    7  10
3  NaN   9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `where` with `between`

```
df.a=df.a.where(df.a.between(min,max),np.nan)
df
Out[146]: 
     a   b
0  5.0  12
1  NaN   3
2  7.0  10
3  NaN   9
```

Or `clip`

```
df.a.clip(min,max)
Out[147]: 
0    5.0
1    NaN
2    7.0
3    NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about `clip`!  It's better than my where/between, but I think your mask is a little ugly.

Comment: @DSM yep using mask is little bit redundant, since we have where already :-)

Comment: Note: if min is greater than max then all the values will be converted to NaN using `df.a.between(min,max)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.loc` with `between` also

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 1, 7, 22],'b': [12, 3 , 10, 9]})

min = 2
max = 7

df.loc[~df.a.between(min,max), 'a'] = np.nan
```